# universal parsing of strings into float

Tags: c#, parsing, floating-point

In the environment that my program is going to run, people use ',' and '.' as decimal separators randomly on PCs with ',' and '.' separators.

How would you implements such a floatparse(string) function?

I tried this one:

```
    try
    {
        d = float.Parse(s);
    }
    catch
    {
        try
        {
            d = float.Parse(s.Replace(".", ","));
        }
        catch
        {
            d = float.Parse(s.Replace(",", "."));
        }
    }
```

It doesn't work. And when I debugg it turns out that it parses it wrong the first time thinking that "." is a separator for thousands (like 100.000.000,0).

I'm noob at C#, so hopefully there is less overcomplicated solution then that :-)

NB: People a going to use both '.' and ',' in PCs with different separator settings.

Comment: What would you like to happen when someone write 100.000.00 ? Do you want it to be treated like 10000.00 or 100.0000 ? Or is it not a number?

Comment: eh, screw more than one non-digit character!

Comment: A more flexible solution might be to allow the user to choose their culture. That way, all numbers and dates can be formatted automatically to what they're used to. Both ToString() and Format() would work without trying to "hack" it.  Or have IT fix the computers so the culture is set correctly....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are sure nobody uses thousand-separators, you can Replace first:

```
string s = "1,23";  // or s = "1.23";

s = s.Replace(',', '.');
double d = double.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The general pattern would be:

- first try to sanitize and normalize. Like Replace(otherChar, myChar).
- try to detect a format, maybe using RegEx, and use a targeted conversion. Like counting . and , to guess whether thousand separators are used.
- try several formats in order, with TryParse. Do *not* use exceptions for this.

Comment: as I understand in Invariant culture separator is always '.' ?

Comment: hm, VS2008EE sais 'CultureInfo' does not exist in current context... do I need to declare it somehow?

Comment: You need to import System.Globalization

Comment: thanks, that works! do you know if it is possible to set culture as InvariantCulture globally in a program?

Comment: You can't set InvariantCulture for a thread. You need to pass it into the `Single.TryParse()` method as the `IFormatProvider` parameter.

Comment: @Halst: Invariant is just a convenient choice for this, but you could pick another fixed culture.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing uses the settings of the [CultureInfo.CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx), which reflects the language  and the Number format selected by the user through Regional Settings. If your users type the decimals that correspond to the language they chose for their computers, you should have no problem using plain old double.Parse(). If a user sets his locale to Greek and types "8,5", double.Parse("8,5") will return 8.5. If he types "8.5" parse will return 85.

If a user sets his locale to one setting and then starts using the wrong decimal, you face a problem. There is no clean way to separate such wrong entries instead of entries that really wanted to enter the grouping character. What you can do is to warn the user when a number is too short to include a grouping character and use Masked or numerical text boxes to prevent wrong entries.

Another, somewhat stricter option, is to disallow the grouping character for number entry in your application by cancelling it in the KeyDown event of your textboxes. You can get the numeric and grouping characters from [CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.numberformat.aspx) property.

Trying to replace the decimal and grouping characters is doomed to fail as it depends on knowing during compile time what kind of separator the user is going to use. If you knew that, you could just parse the number using the CultureInfo in the user's mind. Unfortunately, User.Brain.CultureInfo is not yet part of the .NET framework :P

Answer (score 1):

I would do someting like this

```
float ConvertToFloat(string value)
{
    float result;

    var converted  = float.TryParse(value, out result);

    if (converted) return result;

    converted = float.TryParse(value.Replace(".", ",")), 
                               out result);

    if (converted) return result;

    return float.NaN;
}
```

In this case the following would return correct data

```
        Console.WriteLine(ConvertToFloat("10.10").ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(ConvertToFloat("11,0").ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(ConvertToFloat("12").ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(ConvertToFloat("1 . 10").ToString());
```

**Returns**

```
10,1
11
12
NaN
```

In this case if it is not possible to convert it, you will at least know that it is not a number. It's a safe way to convert.

You can also use the following overload

```
float.TryParse(value,
            NumberStyles.Currency,
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            out result)
```

On this test-code:

```
Console.WriteLine(ConvertToFloat("10,10").ToString());
Console.WriteLine(ConvertToFloat("11,0").ToString());
Console.WriteLine(ConvertToFloat("12").ToString());
Console.WriteLine(ConvertToFloat("1 . 10").ToString());
Console.WriteLine(ConvertToFloat("100.000,1").ToString());
```

It returns the following

```
10,1
11
12
110
100000,1
```

So depending on how "nice" you want to be to the user, you can always replace the last step, if it is not a number, try converting it this way aswell, otherwsie it really isn't a number.

It would the look like this

```
float ConvertToFloat(string value)
{
    float result;

    var converted = float.TryParse(value,
                                    out result);


    if (converted) return result;

    converted = float.TryParse(value.Replace(".", ","),
                                out result);

    if (converted) return result;

    converted = float.TryParse(value,
                                    NumberStyles.Currency,
                                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                    out result);

    return converted ? result : float.NaN;
}
```

Where the following

```
Console.WriteLine(ConvertToFloat("10,10").ToString());
Console.WriteLine(ConvertToFloat("11,0").ToString());
Console.WriteLine(ConvertToFloat("12").ToString());
Console.WriteLine(ConvertToFloat("1 . 10").ToString());
Console.WriteLine(ConvertToFloat("100.000,1").ToString());
Console.WriteLine(ConvertToFloat("asdf").ToString());
```

Returns

```
10,1
11
12
110
100000,1
NaN
```

Comment: on PCs with european format 'var converted' will be always true becouse it ignores '.' since it thinks that '.' is thousands separator (100.000.000,0)

Comment: My computer is European and 100.000.000,0 doesn't work at all. You can set the second parameter NumberStyles and the CultureInfo aswell.

Comment: ok, maybe it's just something special about (my) danish PC 'culture', but [var converted = float.TryParse(value, out result); ]  gives 123456 when input was 123.456 and returns true

Comment: You can set the two additional parameters to fix that.